# In any but the most vestigial and nostalgic way...?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, paraphrasing

Once again, here I am with a question raised by the highly unintelligable Hitchens...

It can be equally useful and instructive to take a glimpse at the closing of religions, or religious movements. The Millerites, for example, are no more. And we shall not hear again, **in any but the most vestigial and nostalgic way**, of Pan or Osiris or any of the thousands of gods who once held people in utter thrall. *god is not Great* by Christopher Hitchens, p. 169

As a result of a long and tedious searh, I have -rightly, I hope- concluded that **any but the most XXX** means "all the other things except for the one which is the most XXX". Oddly enough, I can't figure out the exact meaning of **vestigial** in the phrase in bold in the above quote and can't come up with a meaningful explanation of the whole phrase either.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Grammatically, this is a [_Nobbut_-Cleft](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf). The _any_ is ungrammatical without the _not_ in _we shall not hear again,_ and that governs the whole sentence. The whole thing means 'we will hear of them -- if at all -- **only** in the most etc, etc.'

Comment: @John Lawler - I'd never encountered the *Nobbut*-Cleft before, thanks Professor.

Comment: Just another kind of Cleft, which is just another kind of emphatic sentence arrangement.

Comment: One very minor correction (which I hope you will appreciate, just as I appreciate minor corrections in my understanding of my own second language). You have 'concluded that _any but the most XXX_ means _"all the other things except for the one which is the most XXX"_. ' Not quite: _the most XXX_ here simply means something which is especially XXX. For example, _it would terrify all but the most courageous person_ doesn't mean that you would have to be the most courageous person in the world, just that you would have to be exceptionally courageous, to avoid being terrified.

Comment: @Morton - yes sir, good point.

Comment: @John Lawler - That's a really interesting thing to learn. Thank you very much. I think Nobbut-Cleft (which I didn't know even existed) explains a lot. Yet again, you've stated that it would be ungrammatical without _not_.

Comment: Sorry @JohnLawler, I'm new here and trying to get used to commenting properly.                                                                              I came across some material which (as far as I can see) lacks _not_ in this phrase. Here you are: [BBC](http://http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/7263494.stm/) and [Google](http://https://www.google.com.tr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22any%20but%20the%20most%22/) (**I can't give the links to google books since they're too long for the comment section.) I hope you don't mind considering these. Thank you again.

Comment: @Morton - Your are absolutely welcome to suggest any correction. And you are completely right. I will take _most_ here as _especially_. Thank you very much.

Comment: @A.K. -- no worries.

Comment: @Morton: No, I didn't conclude that at all; _any_ is not the same as _all_. The point is that _not...any_ is the negation that's required for the nobbut-cleft form, which has been around for quite a long time and shows up in elegant  writing like this. And I didn't see the need to take on the gratuitous superlative of the final phrase; it is what it is and its structure is left as an exercise for the curious.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was addressing the OP, not your comment. Sorry for the misunderstanding - I can see why it was confusing, and I'll remember to be clearer about it next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vestigial in this context means all but a very small remnant of something that was once much larger or more noticeable.

> [**vestigial**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=vestigial+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=vestigial+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.5.2473268...........0.oZUaei90Lfo&gws_rd=ssl) *adjective*: forming a very small remnant of something that was once much larger or more noticeable. "he felt a *vestigial* flicker of anger from last night"; *synonyms*: remaining, surviving, residual, leftover, lingering. see, Google

Nostalgic is used to mean characterized by or exhibiting feelings of nostalgia. i.e., expressing a romantic or sentimental sensibility.

> [**nostalgia**](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=nostalgia+definition&oq=nostalgia+definition&gs_l=serp.1.0.0i67j0i7i30l9.13117.15326.0.18372.2.2.0.0.0.0.143.281.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.2.277.DKFKW9LUxSU) *noun*: a sentimental longing or wistful affection for the past, typically for a period or place with happy personal associations. "I was overcome with acute *nostalgia* for my days in college";  *synonyms*: reminiscence, remembrance, recollection. see, Google

So, Mr. Hitchens is expressing the opinion that we shall not be hearing much of the gods Pan and Osiris (or any of the thousands of gods who once held people in utter thrall) because reason has vanquished them and all that is left of these gods is a very small remnant (i.e., in literature and myth), therefore only someone suffering from nostalgia, who has a romantic, sentimental and backward-looking understanding of the irrational concept of supernatural deities, is likely to discuss "the gods" at all.

Comment: That's really a comprehensive explanation. It helps me understand the actual meaning of the whole sentence. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure, A.K. Hope you enjoy ELU. :-)